# Remove 2-byte white space in Perl

Tags: perl, special-characters

I have a text document converted from pdf that contains white space I am not able to match and replace. I managed to print its ord() value and got 194, and length() on the character returned 2 (thus I assume it's 2 bytes). How can I remove this character in Perl? Thanks.

Comment: The original pdf (looks like a slide in pdf) does not have Â, and the character in the converted text is not visible. Just printed chr() and gave "\c@". I can replace it by pasting the (invisible) character into perl expression, but was hoping for a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The first character is 194<sub>10</sub> = C2<sub>16</sub> = Â

Seeing as that's not whitespace, and seeing that C2<sub>16</sub> is commonly found at the start of UTF-8 multi-byte sequences, it appears that you forgot to decode the text. That's the first thing you need to do.

Then, you'll probably find that you have U+00A0 NO BREAK SPACE. You can remove it with

```
s/\xA0//
```

Comment: Yes, it is C2 A0. Thanks!

Comment: If the file has UTF-8 encoding, then it should be read as an UTF-8 encoded file. `open my $fh, '<:encoding(utf8)', $file or die $!;`